# i cannot delete related records with a recursive function

Tags: laravel, recursion, orm, relationship

I am trying to manual delete some records from related table, in laravel.
I need a recursive funtion to solve even son of the son case.

- $cciActvity ---hasOne-->cciMonitoring

I must cancel the monitor and leave the main activity on the db;

- $ccieActivity (optional)--hasOne--> subActivity
- $subActvity (optional)---hasOne--> subActivity and each subAtctivy
  can have one subActvity etc.,
- subActivty (optional) ---hasOne-->cciMonitoring monitoring    like
  any other actvity.

The keys are stored on the father side for activity/subAct-->activity carry the external key;

When I go to cancel a monitor:

- i check if the activty monitored have some subAct;
- if yes, i check if this subAct have monitoring, and in case i deleting it;
- I check if the subAct have more subAct, and i try to call recursivly the same function;
- I set actvity external key to null ;
- I deleting subAct;

  ```
   private function delSubAct($ccieActivity)
           {
               if($ccieActivity->has('subActivity')){
                   $subAct=$ccieActivity->subActivity()->first();
                   if($subAct){
                       if($subAct->has('ccie_activity_monitorings')){
                           $monitoringSubActivity= $subAct->ccie_activity_monitorings()->first();
                           if($monitoringSubActivity){
                               $monitoringSubActivity->delete();
                           }
                       }                           

                   }                                                

               } 
               $ccieActivity->subAct=null;
               $ccieActivity->save();
               if($spostata->has('attSpost'))
                       {
                           return $this->delSubAct($spostata);
                       }
               if($spostata){
                   $spostata->delete();           

               }
               return ;

           }
  ```

Please mind that the main monitoring is -corretctly- deleted on the function that call this one.

With:

```
[activty1 , subActivity1 ] ---->[activityMonitoring1]
[subActvity1 , subActivity2] --->[activityMonitoring2]
[subActivity2]
```

Deleting monitoring 1, should result:
[activty1] , all the rest set to null or deleted.

But the  above code, in this scenario, give me:

```
[activty1 , subActivity1 ] 
[subActvity1 , subActivity2] 
[subActivity2]
```

So the subActivity part is not touched, why?
The model are corrects to me, and i print many dd(); for check them;

The related model is:

```
class CcieActivity extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'ccieActivities';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $with = ['project','subAct];


    protected $casts = [
        'project_id' => 'int'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'project_id',
        'catAttivita',
        'nomeAttivita',
        'modalitaRealizzazionePrevista',
        'descrizione',
        'dataInizioPrevista',
        'dataFinePrevista',
        'numNegoziAderentiPrevisti',
        'numAziendeCoinvoltePreviste',
        'numInfluencerPartecipantiPrevisti',
        'numBuyerPrevistiB2B',
        'budgetTotalePrevisto',
        'subAct',
    ];

    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }

    public function ccie_activity_monitorings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CcieActivityMonitoring::class, 'ccieActivity_id');
    }

    public function subActivity(){
        return $this->belongsTo(CcieActivity::class,'subAct','id',);

    }
    public function attOrig()
    {

        return $this->hasOne(CcieActivity::class,'subAct','id');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was how return for the recursive function and the method used for checking model's relation existence.
A model do not have ->has('relation') aviable since is returned from a ->get() or a ->first() etc.
I use insted:

```
$model->relation()->exists()
```

And this is the correct code of the function:

```
private function cancSpost($ccieActivity) //114-1 115-2
        

{


                $spostata=$ccieActivity->attSpost()->first(); //116-2


                if($spostata){
                    if($spostata->ccie_activity_monitorings()->exists()){ //si 107-1 //no-2
                        $monitoringSpostata= $spostata->ccie_activity_monitorings()->first();

                        if($monitoringSpostata){
                            $monitoringSpostata->delete(); //107 via-1
                        }
                    }  
                    $ccieActivity->attivitaSpostata= null ; //115-2=chiavi null
                    $ccieActivity->save();


                    if($spostata->attSpost()->exists())
                    {
                        $this->cancSpost($spostata); //98-1
                        $spostata->delete();
                        return;
                    }elseif($spostata->attSost()->exists())
                    {
                        $this->cancSost($spostata); //98-1
                        $spostata->delete();
                        return;
                    }else{
                        $spostata->delete();
                        return;
                    }
                }else{
                    return;
                }
```